# Block Windows 10 Updates By Firewall

Tags: windows, firewall, updates

Is it possible to block Windows 10 Update servers on a firewall by IP, name, and port? Looking to use Windows 10 Pro in a work environment without having it update?
If this is possible, what are your thoughts on any affects this may cause to Windows 10 Pro. Do you think disconnecting they system from MS will cause it to unauthenticated the license or cause other issues.
We are currently testing this too, will update if we have success.

Comment: You cannot block updates if you are using Windows 10 Professional.  Upgrade to Windows 10 Enterprise.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. We cannot get authorization for the extra cost of Enterprise. I am pretty sure that if you block the right ports and IP/hostname(s) that the updates can possibly be blocked. I also believe that there are reg keys and maybe some .dll's can be configured to also stop Windows 10 from updating.

Comment: @Adroid - If you want to control when updates are installed, just use WSUS, and don't publish any updates.  Blocking Windows Update seems like a really bad idea, if your not using WSUS, since that also means your not installing security updates.

Comment: However, I do not know the repercussions that may happen to the OS.

Comment: @Adroid - That is your job to figure out.   I cannot list every possible repercussion from using WSUS.

Comment: Ramhound - Thanks, but this Windows 10 PC (not domain, we have both) automatically updates via the Internet. Thanks for the info though.

Comment: Repercussions from "blocking Windows updates," was writing when you posted. I am pretty sure our finance department is not going to authorize the purchase of a WSUS server if they wont even upgrade me to Enterprise. Thanks again.

Comment: It sounds like you should generate a plan, to implement WSUS, if Windows 10 automatic updates isn't acceptable.  Unless you want to block all updates, your stuck with accepting the new service model, unless you use WSUS.  Which is what the duplicate says basically.

Comment: @Ramhound - As I said, we will not get any funds for a WSUS implementation. I think you answered my question on your first reply - You cannot block updates...I beg to differ, I think you can via a firewall.

Answer (score 1):

Yes Indeed.  I did it the manual way in many locations.

If I recall, this was the minimum, there may be more.

Computer>right-click>manage

> Scheduled Tasks>Microsoft>Windows Updates> delete all or disable

(also,delete all,Telemetry)
<

> Group Policy Editor. 
>   run as administrator 
>   gpedit.msc
>   look for updates and disable all users except ?
>
> win+X >Services
>
> - disable Windows Updates
> - Control Panel > Windows Updates
>
>   - disable

This also,affects Metro live updates, (news weather sports) which may fill Event Logs with errors under Windows Apps...

To verify after... Get/run Procmon.exe and trace only process name = wupdt.exe or wuauclt.exe

Comment: Please read the author's question again.  They are not trying to block the  Windows 10 update.  They are trying to block updates on Windows 10.  There a reason you wrote "Steve Gibson" the way you did?

Comment: fat fingers on iPad.. I knew, but couldn't resist .  Win 7 should be good for a long time . He said, there was nothing that could convince him to install Win X. I agree.

Comment: You should read the question again.  This does not answer the author's question.  The author's question was, **"How does one block Windows 10 updates on Windows 10 Professional"**, you should edit your answer.

Comment: The answer applies to blocking Windows updates for 8 or 10

Comment: I don't see how the tool is relevant.

Comment: I appreciate your concern

Comment: this one is great, just change delete to disable